# Calculate a formula in a Finite Field

Tags: algorithm, go, secret-key, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to transform a formula over to a finite-field equivalent of that formula.

The formula can be seen below:
[image]

Now I have this implemented and it works correctly, but I need this in a finite-field, which means that I introduce a **p**, let's say `p = 183269` andd take `mod p` but how exactly does the above formula change? Do I just `mod p` after i'm done calculating the formula normally?

Example:

I have the polynomial: `f(x) = 1234 + 631x + 442x^2`
I generated 6 random points: `(x, f(x) mod p)`

```
1. (108, 93338)
2. (413, 146507)
3. (260, 171647)
4. (819, 98605)
5. (359, 13237)
6. (894, 118490)
```

Now, what I want is to reconstruct **1234** given any 3 points using the above formula, but it gives me incorrect value.

here is my code:

```
// x_input = [108, 413, 260]
    var reconstructed float64 = 0.0

    for _, k := range x_input { 
        var y float64 = float64(points[k])
        var pr_x float64 = 1.0

        for _, l := range x_input {
            if l != k {
                var aux_k float64 = float64(k)
                var aux_l float64 = float64(l)
                pr_x *= (aux_l / (aux_l - aux_k))
            }
        }

        y *= pr_x
        reconstructed += y
    }
```

I'm trying to implement [SSSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing)

EDIT

As pointed out by `@user58697` I had some mistakes in my code and understanding of finite fields. I managed to rewrite my formula and it looks like this:

```
reconstructed := 0

    for _, k := range x_input { 
        y := points[k]
        pr_x := 1
        for _, l := range x_input {
            if l != k {
                inv := mod_inverse(l - k, p)
                pr_x *= inv
            }
        }
        y *= pr_x
        reconstructed += y
    }

    return reconstructed % p

func mod_inverse(a, p int) int {

    if a < 0 { // negative numbers are not allowed
        a = a * -1
    }

    for i := 1; i < p; i++ {
        if ((a % p) * (i % p)) % p == 1 {
            return i
        }
    }

    return p
}
```

Unfortunately, it still has one or more bugs because it doesn't produce `f(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I just mod p after i'm done calculating the formula normally?

No. First you have to compute a multiplicative inverse of `x[m] - x[j]` modulo `p`. That is a tricky part to implement efficiently. The rest is indeed just multiplications and summation modulo `p`.

Keep in mind that floating point operations cannot work in the finite field. Everything there is precise in a sense of integers.

PS: to address a concerns about division, this is how division works in a finite field:

`y/x` is in fact `y * z` where `z` is a multiplicative inverse of `x`, that is `x * z = 1 mod p`. For example, let's use 7 for `p`. A multiplicative inverse of, say 2 is 4: `2 * 4 == 8 (== 1 mod 7)`. This means that `3/2 mod 7` is `3 * 4 mod 7`, that is `5`.

Comment: But when dividing, can it not produce floating point numbers?

Comment: Thanks, and what if there is no modular multiplicative inverse for an integer? for example ```110``` and ```1832```?

Comment: A multiplicative inverse of `x` modulo `p` is guaranteed to exist if `x` is coprime to `p`. If `p` is prime it is always the case. Otherwise, tough luck (it is not a _field_ anymore, BTW). That is why primes are so important in cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it in mind that always to modulo the result after multiplying two numbers. `a*b*c` can cause int overflow if `a<p,b<p,c<p` for `p=183269`. And if `p` is larger (like `998244353`), `a*b` can simply cause overflow. For this case, before multiplying two numbers `a` and `b`, you should cast them into `int64` and modulo the result by `p` and finally cast it back to `int`.

And another point here: `a` is not always equivalent with `-a` when modulo `p`. Actually this is false in most cases. You should use `a = (a % p + p) % p` instead.

Below are the modified code that could produce the correct result (I just learned golang for this question so forgive me for possible improper code):

```golang
    reconstructed := 0
    for _, k := range x_input {
        y := points[k]
        pr_x := 1
        for _, l := range x_input {
            if l != k {
                inv := mod_inverse(l - k, p)
                // You forgot to multiply pr_x by l
                // pr_x *= inv
                pr_x = pr_x * inv % p * l % p
            }
        }
        y = y * pr_x % p
        reconstructed += y
    }

    return reconstructed % p
```

```golang
func mod_inverse(a, p int) int {

    if a < 0 { // negative numbers are not allowed
        // The following line is wrong! (a % p) == (a % p + p) % p when a < 0, but not -a
        // a = a * -1
        a = ((a % p) + p) % p
    }

    for i := 1; i < p; i++ {
        if ((a % p) * (i % p)) % p == 1 {
            return i
        }
    }

    // I suspect whether you should report an error here instead of returning p
    return p
}
```

BTW, the time complexity of `mod_inverse` is `O(p)`, which can be inefficient in most cases. You can use [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the multiplicative inverse of `x` modulo `p` in `O(log p)` time. Also, the multiplicative inverse of `x` modulo `p` is simply `(x^(p-2)) % p` when `p` is prime, and you can calculate that fast using [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Both methods has `O(log p)` complexity, but the later one is easier to implement.

Sorry for my poor English. Feel free to point out my typos and mistakes.